# Android library throwing exception inside try block that catches all Throwable

Tags: java, android, kotlin

We've written a Kotlin library to handle some networking logic. The library itself contains an `AsyncTask` that uses the `HttpURLConnection` facilities in `java.net.*`.

```
private inner class ClickstreamTask(
                                    headers: HashMap<String, String>,
                                    params: Request,
                                    success: (() -> Unit)? = null,
                                    failure: ((statusCode: Int?, json: 
HashMap<String, String>?) -> Unit)? = null) : AsyncTask<Void, Unit, Unit>() {

    private var headers: HashMap<String, String> = headers
    private var paramaters: Request = params
    private var success: (() -> Unit)? = success
    private var failure: ((statusCode: Int?, json: HashMap<String, String>?) -> Unit)? = failure

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void){

        val url = try {
            URL(getURLString() + path)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            failure?.invoke(null, hashMapOf("error" to "Invalid URL."))
            return Unit
        }

        var request = try{
            url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        } catch (e: Exception){
            failure?.invoke(null, hashMapOf("error" to "Unable to establish connection"))
            return Unit
        }

        request.doInput = false
        request.doOutput = true
        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

        request.requestMethod = "POST"
        val httpBody = try {
            mapper.writeValueAsBytes(paramaters)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            failure?.invoke(null, hashMapOf("error" to "Invalid params."))
            return Unit
        }

        for ((key, value) in headers) {
            request.setRequestProperty(key, value)
        }

        try{
            request.outputStream.write(httpBody)
        }catch (e: Throwable){
            request.outputStream.close()
            failure?.invoke(null, hashMapOf("error" to "Issue writing to URL"))
            return Unit
        }
        request.outputStream.close()


        if (request.responseCode != 200){
            failure?.invoke(request.responseCode, hashMapOf("Failed request" to request.responseMessage))
            return Unit
        }

        success?.invoke()
        return Unit
    }
}
```

When we use the Android app that exercises the library in airplane mode, the app crashes because of an uncaught exception "UnknownHostException":

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "ste03lbclkapp00.iteclientsys.local": No address associated with
>   hostname  at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:141)
>     at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
>     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)  at
>   com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)  at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
>     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown
>   Source:0)     at
>   com.tdameritrade.amerivest.clickstreamshared.Network.NetworkManager$ClickstreamTask.doInBackground(NetworkManager.kt:87)
>     at
>   com.tdameritrade.amerivest.clickstreamshared.Network.NetworkManager$ClickstreamTask.doInBackground(NetworkManager.kt:43)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  ... 4 more
>   Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed:
>   EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)  at
>   libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)   at
>   libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:59)     at
>   java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:122)
>     ... 24 more

The line that is throwing the exception is `request.outputStream.write(httpBody)`. However, we are wrapping that line in a `try / catch` that handles `Throwable`.

How is `doOnBackground()` line 87 throwing an exception when it's wrapped in a catch?

Comment: Catching `Throwable` is a very bad idea though

Comment: It was `Exception` and I changed it to `Throwable` just to test

Comment: In your 'throwable' exception block you then attempt to access request.outputstream.close - which I'd guess is then throwing the exception which is outside a catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
    try{
        request.outputStream.write(httpBody)
    }catch (e: Throwable){
        request.outputStream.close()
        failure?.invoke(null, hashMapOf("error" to "Issue writing to URL"))
        return Unit
    }
```

will attempt to perform an operation in the catch block which can also generate an exception:

```
        request.outputStream.close()
```

This is uncaught - but also seems ill-advised given you are processing *some* error in accessing the outputstream.

The exception trace indicates more caused by and I'd guess digging further you'd fine this one.

Comment: I've removed the stream close from the catch and no change in behavior

Comment: Post the complete stack trace...there's more - the useful stuff is usually at the bottom of the caused-by chain.  Surround the whole 'doinbackground' code with a try/catch throwable and log exception.

Comment: K, when I get back from lunch I'll try it. Thanks